# Replace characters where certain character does not follow a comma?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Is there a way to use wildcards to define the following:

I would like a `"\"` to come before and after a comma, when a comma character does not contain a `"\""` before it or after it.

I am a little unsure how to do the negation.

EDIT Sample data:

```
"col1,col2,col3"
```

should become

```
"\"col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\""
```

where "\"" just means a quote string

Comment: Please show some sample input and output data.

Comment: That's not the whole truth. Please show sample data for the second part of your requirements: *when a comma character does not contain a "\"" before it or after it*

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions or a simple replace:

```
string s = "col1,col2\",\"col3";
// replace all existing quotes and replace all commas with escaped characters again
string r = s.Replace('\"','').Replace(",","\",\"");
// r = "col1\",\"col2\",\"col3"
```

But this does not do what your sample data looks like:

```
"col1,col2,col3" should become "col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\""
```

This isn't following your rule (look at the trailing `\"` !). Maybe you want to wrap all col's, so you can add a `\"` at the beginning and the end, too. (Assuming the seperator is always just `,`, not including spaces)

Comment: Sorry I missed out the quote at the start, yes it should also do this. I have edited my question.

Comment: then just add \" at the beginning and the end and you should get what you want :-)

Comment: I dont think you can use this because the second replace will pattern match a comma, even if the comma already has a quote before it. You will end up with Quote, Quote, Comma, Quote?

Comment: @user1107474 if your string can only be like `col1,col2` or `col1\",\"col2` then my replace will work, otherwise you need to replace all partial quotes too. I adapt my answer to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything that matches the following: `^(\\\"),^(\\\")` with: `\",\"`

It means anything but a backslash followed by a quote, followed by a comma, followed by anything but a backslash followed by a quote.

Comment: Is that definitely correct as it wont compile, are you missing quotes somewhere?

Comment: Could be, didn't test it myself. Just gave a general regex which I'm used to building in Java... Should have known the quote was still going to be a problem. Escape it so it becomes (\\\") in both groups. Also make the ^ before the group, or it will be wrong... going to edit now.

Comment: Regex.Replace(Line,"^(\\\"),^(\\\")","\",\"") doesnt appear to work? (Apologies if I have inserted quotes in wrong place)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "negative look behind" assertion:

```
(?<!\\),
```

Can't give you a better answer without having sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?<!\"),(?!\")`, which is called [Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

I'll busy now, would explain later, sorry for that.

Comment: Do you mean? Regex.Replace(Line,"(?<!\")","(?!\")") ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old but for the new visitors this can also be done:

```
string sample = "col1,col2,col3" 
string result = sample.Replace("""","");
result = "\"" + result.replace(",","\",\"") + "\""
```

Hope it helps!